# Can static variable be re-initialised

Tags: c, function, static, output

In the ***main()*** function,
***i,a and b*** are decalred ***static***. Ok, fair enough.
The **function is called**.
All ***i,a and b*** have some value. Ok, fair enough.

The function is **called again**.
Now as a static variable ***i , a and b*** must retain their value.
But
***How is i again intialised to 0?*** (Shouldnt it contain its previous value?)

[Snap shot of the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OamF3.jpg)

P.s Answer is ***d*** btw.

Comment: Please post your code in the question as *text*. And it should be [mcve].

Comment: `static` simply means the objects exist even before `main()` starts (though they have a limited scope to the function they are defined in) and their values is whatever is in their initialization (or `0`). As any other variable, static objects cannot be *re-initialised*, but they can be assigned new values at anytime.

Comment: What a poor, poor question. I mean the linked one, not the one asked here. There's half a dozen issues with that code even on first glance, that wouldn't fly in a code review. Why do students get inflicted with wilfully obfuscated code problems, instead of getting shown well-formed, clear code as an example to follow?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Extremely sorry, I shall not repeat the mistake. I do relaise it becomes cumbersome this way. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @pmg I do see what you are saying and tht solves all the confusion. Thank you for the explanation. Really helpful.

Comment: @DevSolar well, since I am new to c , often in my free time, I  just youtube some problems. I'm afraid I'm not yet there to judge whether a question is bad or good.

Comment: The `swap` function is a no-op. I stopped reading after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`i` is **not** initialized again:

```
void printtab()
{
    static int i, a = -3, b = -6;
    i = 0;
    ...
```

It is *assigned* a new value when the function is entered.

Comment: So can I assign a and b another value this way as well?

Comment: @Teaquila Yes, in fact the code already does that a few lines down.